# Passing CStrings between projects in same solution

Tags: c++, string, dll, mfc

this is my class

```
namespace AuthenticationAdapter
{
    class  OPENID_EXPORT_API AuthenticationHelper
        {
            public:
                static CString isOpenIdAuthentication( CString hostUrl, bool &isOpenId );
                static CString Authenticate( CString hostUrl, CString& tokenId);

        };
};
```

this is openidExport.h

```
#ifndef OPENIDEXPORT_H
#define OPENIDEXPORT_H

#ifdef OPENID_EXPORT
    #define OPENID_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define OPENID_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#endif
```

this is the implementation

```
namespace AuthenticationAdapter
{
    CString AuthenticationHelper::isOpenIdAuthentication( CString hostUrl,bool &isOpenId )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

this is the call

```
CString error = AuthenticationAdapter::AuthenticationHelper::isOpenIdAuthentication( 
            url,
            connection->m_isOpenId);
```

and this is the error, both projects use unicode, i can get round it by using LPCTSTR instead, but i would love to know what the problem is.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class 
ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class 
ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > __cdecl 
AuthenticationAdapter::AuthenticationHelper::isOpenIdAuthentication(class 
ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class 
ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,bool &)" 
(?isOpenIdAuthentication@AuthenticationHelper@AuthenticationAdapter@@SA?AV?
$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V34@AA_N@Z) 
referenced in function "public: class CServerConnection * __thiscall 
CGlobalData::getAuthDetails(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?
getAuthDetails@CGlobalData@@QAEPAVCServerConnection@@PB_W0H@Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are exporting `CString` at the DLL interface boundaries. If so, make sure that all the projects using that DLL and the DLL itself are **dynamically linked** to the **same flavor** of the **CRT** and **MFC** libraries.

---

In addition, in your question code you wrote an explicit fixed `__declspec(dllexport)`:

> ```
> namespace AuthenticationAdapter
> {
>   class  __declspec(dllexport) AuthenticationHelper
>   {
>    public:
>     static CString isOpenIdAuthentication( CString hostUrl, bool &isOpenId );
>     static CString Authenticate( CString hostUrl, CString& tokenId);
>   };
> }
> ```

You should `dllexport` when building the DLL, but `dllimport` when *using* it in client projects.

So, consider using an adaptable `dllimport`/`dllexport` pattern, e.g.:

```
// In DLL header

// Client code hasn't defined MYDLL_API,
// so dllimport in clients.
#ifndef MYDLL_API
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace AuthenticationAdapter
{
  class MYDLL_API AuthenticationHelper
  {
...
```

In the DLL implementation `.cpp` file:

```
// Define *before* including DLL header,
// to export DLL stuff
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

#include "MyDll.h" // Include DLL header

// DLL implementation code ...
```

Comment: how do i check this is vs2010?

Comment: @WendyLisaGibbons: Select project properties, and under "General" check that you have **"Use MFC in a Shared DLL"**. Moreover, under "C/C++|Code Generation" check that "Runtime Library" is properly set to Multi-threaded DLL (or Multi-threaded Debug DLL for debug builds).

Comment: sorry, i thought i was simplifying the code by doing this, added the full version with the added header file

Comment: about the export...i did find a problem that OPENID_EXPORT wasn't included in my pre-processor settings

Comment: @WendyLisaGibbons: I saw that you modified your code. You should `#define OPENID_EXPORT` inside the .cpp source file where you implement your DLL code, _before_ including your DLL public header.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your `isOpenIdAuthentication` method in your class, but you probably don't implement it anywhere.

Update:
You should include both the namespace and class in the signature. Also, you should not declare your namespace again.

This:

```
namespace AuthenticationAdapter
{
CString AuthenticationHelper::isOpenIdAuthentication( CString hostUrl,bool &isOpenId )
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
CString AuthenticationHelper::AuthenticationHelper::isOpenIdAuthentication( CString hostUrl,bool &isOpenId )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i didn't include the implementation as i felt it didn't really add any extra information, as the signature was exactly the same.

Comment: For some reason your compiler does not find it. Probably you should share it, at least the signature.

Comment: added to the opening post

Comment: She wrote her work around would be using raw C string pointers (e.g. `LPCTSTR`) instead of `CString`. This makes me think that her problem is in sharing the `CString` at the module boundaries, with a mismatch in CRT/MFC flavors. All in all, `CString` is based on the `CStringT` template, and there are several parameters that can change (in addition to the `char`/`wchar_t` character type), like the particular string traits, etc.